# How is it possible to increase mercury's specific weight?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, elements

Is it possible to change mercury's specific weight to make it heavier? By mixing it with anything? But not by changing its temperature.

Comment: Mix it with osmium.

Comment: Gold might be a cheaper option.

Comment: Is the mixture a liquid at room temperature? And if you could please tell me about the mixing process ? Ive heard that there's a way to "cheat"it and make it heavier.

Comment: @IvanNeretin not necessarily. At current market prices, gold is more expensive than any other precious metal.

Comment: Yeah, I know, those prices tend to oscillate wildly, hence "_might be_".

Comment: Use $\ce{^{203}Hg}$ instead. It's 0.5% heavier.

Comment: Even if gold is more expensive than osmium, I would still go for the gold.  Osmium generates a volatile oxide making it more hazardous to work with.  Or get a metallic asteroid with a lot of siderophiles into Earth orbit and the price problem is solved.  ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Specific weight is a property of the element. It is product of the atomic mass and the volume. You can't easily alter either.

You could mix an element with another element of a different density and the density of the mixture will change. But you won't be changing the specific mass of the *elements*, just creating a *mixture* with a different density.

You can't readily change the mass of an element. But an element might be made up of multiple isotopes (mercury has 4 significant ones with masses ranging from 199 to 202 atomic mass units). If you enrich the mercury for one of those isotopes, you can change the mass, very slightly (for other elements this can be important; fissile isotopes of uranium are concentrated by doing it when making nuclear fuels).

In practice there is nothing practical you can do to alter the density (specific mass) of an element though you can create mixtures with different densities (but then you still haven't altered the properties of the element itself).

Comment: 7 observationally stable isotopes with 204 being the highest according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_mercury

Comment: @DavePhD Fair point. I was summarising the top 4 with >10% natural abundance. And I didn't read the full list. ;-)

Comment: Surely you _can_ alter the density of _some_ elements -- allotropes of the same element often have different densities. Diamond is about 1.5 times as dense as graphite; there's a similar difference between black and white phosphorus. Liquid ozone is denser than liquid oxygen.